# How to create a textbox based on a dropdown selection in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a an object which looks like:

```
public class Emailing
{
   public string EmailName { get; set; }
   public List<string> EmailRecipients { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a dropdownlist which displays list of `EmailName` and depending on the `EmailName`, I want to display number of textboxes for `EmailRecipients`  which users can edit. 
Displaying the list of EmailName works fine. However, I can't make the textbox appear after selection in dropdown is made. I'm guessing I'll need to have some kind of Jquery event on `EmailName` dropdown but I'm not sure what to put there.

**My current view:**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEmailName, Model.EmailingJobsSelectList, EmailingManagementViewModel.DefaultEmailNameListMessage, new { style = "width:250px", @class = "form-control" })

     @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SelectedEmailName))
     {
         foreach (var recipent in Model.EmailingJobs.FirstOrDefault(r => r.EmailName == Model.SelectedEmailName).EmailRecipients)
         {
              @Html.LabelFor(model => recipent, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
              @Html.EditorFor(model => recipent)
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => recipent)

         }
     }
```

**Jquery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#SelectedEmailName").change(function () {
            if ($("#SelectedEmailtName").val() !== "" && $("#SelectedEmailName").val() !== null) {
                   //Something goes here??

            } else {

            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Rendered HTML code:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="SelectedEmailName" name="SelectedEmailtName" style="width:250px"><option value="">Please select an email name</option>
      <option value="Email">Email</option>
      <option value="Email2">Email2</option>
  </select>
```

I can't get the rendered html for the recipient part as `SelectedEmailName` is `NULL` so nothing appears for recipient textboxes when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Can you show us the rendered html code?

Comment: Which html for the textbox needs to be added after selecting an item of the dropdown?

Comment: `<input id="recipient1" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="EmailManagementViewModel.recipient1">  <input id="recipient2" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="EmailManagementViewModel.recipient2">`   //Something like this I'm guessing